# Why not equal displaying actual result in select queries by joining two select tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, mariadb

I am using MySQL. I am trying to join two queries by != condition. For this example it should return empty result set. But it seems the condition is not applied. Why is this so?

My attempts are below:

```
    SELECT today_student.* FROM (
    SELECT scd.student_id, sc.transaction_date
    FROM student_collection_details scd
    INNER JOIN student_collection sc
     ON (scd.student_collection_id = sc.id)
    WHERE 1=1
    AND sc.transaction_date BETWEEN DATE('2022-06-01 00:00:00') AND DATE('2022-06-27 00:00:00')
    AND scd.admission_year_id = 2
    AND scd.month_id = 21
    AND scd.collection_head_id = 9  
    GROUP BY scd.student_id
) prev_student,

(
    SELECT scd.student_id, sc.transaction_date
    FROM student_collection_details scd
    INNER JOIN student_collection sc
     ON (scd.student_collection_id = sc.id)
    WHERE 1=1
    AND sc.transaction_date = DATE('2022-06-28 00:00:00')
    AND scd.admission_year_id = 2
    AND scd.month_id = 21
    AND scd.collection_head_id = 9  
    GROUP BY scd.student_id
) today_student

WHERE 1=1
AND  prev_student.student_id != today_student.student_id
```

prev_student returns:

```
    1196; 2022-06-20 00:00:00
    1861; 2022-06-18 00:00:00
```

today_student returns:

```
1196; 2022-06-28 00:00:00
1861; 2022-06-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: 1196 <> 1861 is true and 1861 <> 1196 is also true. Why do you expect an empty result set?

Comment: Why `where 1=1` try using a proper join this will help i imagine.  Could you show some "data in"?

Comment: @forpas, then how could I achieve the result? any suggestion

Comment: What result? You did not explain what you want.

Comment: @forpas, I want the student will not be in the result set who are already in the prev_student resultset

Comment: I think you want all result from <<today_student>> query that student_id NOT IN <<prev_student>> query?? Is this ok? (( sorry i am not skill in English))

Comment: @hasan yes brother, forpas answer works fine with a simple edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause with the condition that the min `transaction_date` is `'2022-06-28'`:

```
SELECT scd.student_id, 
       MIN(sc.transaction_date) transaction_date
FROM student_collection_details scd INNER JOIN student_collection sc
ON scd.student_collection_id = sc.id
WHERE sc.transaction_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-28 00:00:00'
  AND scd.admission_year_id = 2
  AND scd.month_id = 21
  AND scd.collection_head_id = 9
GROUP BY scd.student_id
HAVING MIN(sc.transaction_date) = '2022-06-28 00:00:00';
```

Comment: this does not show the student who has paid at 2022-06-28 for the first time in this month, a little bit edited as - `select ... , MAX(sc.transaction_date) max_transaction_date ...` and in having clause as - `HAVING min_transaction_date = max_transaction_date
AND min_transaction_date = DATE('2022-06-28')`

Comment: @SumonBappi the condition `WHERE sc.transaction_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-28 00:00:00'` filters out all rows not in between that interval, which means that if the min transaction_date is '2022-06-28 00:00:00' then this is the first one because its is the upper bound of the interval. I used date with time in my code and not just date because I see in your sample data that transaction_date contains time. Also DATE('2022-06-28') is just '2022-06-28' so the function DATE() is not needed.

Comment: After your comment I tried again but no problem found.  it is working, it may be some date change problem.